# How to get regEx for \" string in a given string

Tags: java

We need to give like this :I\"THIS IS TEST[1]\" for the data : I\"THIS IS TEST[1]\" - to be inserted into the Redshift.

But the above thing has to be done only if we have \" in the given string , So i am searching how to identify the \" in a given string, tried with regEx , but no luck. Can you please suggest here how to check if the string has \" so that if a match is found then i will replaceAll ("\"" , "\\"");

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to check whether a String contains the string \" you must firstly match the character \ literally by adding \ to your Regular Expression and then match the " character by adding \".

The end Regular Expression is \\" and this is tested to match your provided string on https://regex101.com/

Quick test:

```
String regex = "\\\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
String toTest = "hi there \". Do I match?";
boolean found = pattern.matcher(toTest).find();
System.out.println("Boolean value for whether pattern matches toTest: "  + found);
```

Output: "Boolean value for whether pattern matches toTest: true"

After found is true, simply run your replaceAll command like so:

```
String#replaceAll(regex, "new value");
```

Note: \" is just a ". \\" will match \". \\\" will match \". Every time you want to match an additional \, just add \\ to your Regular Expression
 - Alternatively, if you want to match an additional " add \" to your Regular Expression

Comment: Thanks Nathan! after the match is true, i given as : 
 `result=pattern.matcher(toTest).replaceAll(regex);
  System.out.println("result::::"+ result);` But no luck , if i have input string like this : I\"TEST STR[1]\ then I get the output as : I"TEST STR[1]"

Comment: No worries, "I\"TEST STR[1]\"".replaceAll(regex, ""); will remove the \" from the string - If you want to replace \" with "\\"" in the string, just replace the empty "" with that :)

Comment: `class Test
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 String regex = "\\\"";
 String result="";
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
 String toTest = "I\"TEST STR[1]\"";
 boolean found = pattern.matcher(toTest).find();
 System.out.println("Boolean value for whether pattern matches toTest: "  + found);
 
 if(found){
  System.out.println("TRUE");
  System.out.println("result::::"+ "I\"TEST STR[1]\"".replaceAll(regex, "\\\""));
 }
}
}` Hey @nathan I am trying with above way of replace but this gives output as I"TEST STR[1]" but i need to get as : I\"TEST STR[1]\" .

Comment: Nathan, Please you can try running this code snippet :)

Comment: Output for the following code is: Found \" inside of I\"TEST STR[1]\" string, new val = I\\"TEST STR[1]\\"

Code = https://pastebin.com/pJYEenyu   If this isn't what you want, then you need to be a bit more specific on what output you want for what input

Comment: \" is just a ".  \\\" will match \".  \\\\\" will match \\".  Every time you want to match an additional \, just add \\ to the Regular Expression ;)

Comment: nathan thanks, the input data is I\"TEST STR[1]\" and the output also wanted as I\"TEST STR[1]\" that is where i am getting the problem.

Comment: Hi can anyone please help with this , please check my last comment.

Comment: Your input & output are the same?

Comment: yes Nathan, the input and output which should go in db is same.

Comment: Hi Can any one help with this please : the input data is I\"TEST STR[1]\" and the output also wanted as I\"TEST STR[1]\"

Comment: Its exactly the same; the input in your reply matches your expected output in your reply? Its the same

Comment: yeah Nathan, but when it gets inserted in db(redshift)  as I"TEST STR[1]" , the \ also has to be inserted , it has to be inserted as I\"TEST STR[1]\" . Please help with this!